# FFmpeg gives warning when Video and Audio Filters are used together

Tags: ffmpeg

Here's an example command I'm using.

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mpg -c:v libvpx -b:v 1300K -crf 20 -vf "deband, dejudder" -c:a libvorbis -q:a 2 -af "lowpass" output.webm
```

It uses **Video Filters** `-vf` `deband` and `dejudder`
and **Audio Filter** `-af` `lowpass`.

---

**Warning**

It gives the warning in [red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F295T.png):

```
Only '-vf deband, dejudder' read, ignoring remaining -vf options: Use ',' to separate filters
Only '-af lowpass' read, ignoring remaining -af options: Use ',' to separate filters
```

However, the filters are separated with a comma.

This warning only displays when both `-vf` and `-af` are used together in the same script.
But does not give the warning when they are used individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore it. It's a false warning, generated due to a buggy check for multiple filterchains specified for the same stream. It has since been [corrected](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/7712), so upgrade to latest git build.

Comment: Thanks, I updated to the Nightly 20200515-b18fd2b and the warning went away.